# Can't get LLDB to run my executable correctly

Tags: c, clang, lldb

recently i decided to experiment with clang and it works. (that is not the problem)
BUT i got an floating point when i tried to run it. i searched the clang debugger
and got LLDB, went to installed it (lldb-14-dev and liblldb-dev via synaptic)
maybe i am missing some. probably
when i try running it (lldb ./out/roguelike launch) this is what i get:

```
clang -Wall -Werror -lm *.c -o out/roguelike `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lm
lldb .out/roguelike launch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lldb.embedded_interpreter'
(lldb) target create ".out/roguelike"
error: unable to find executable for '.out/roguelike'
```

this is likely because i missed some lldb thing or forgot some argument (unfortunate)
but i don't know it for certain. tho if it matters (not likely) here is my makefile:

```
CC = clang

lazy_compile:
    $(CC) -Wall -Werror -lm *.c -o out/roguelike `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lm

lazy_test: lazy_compile
    ./out/roguelike

compile:
    $(CC) -O3 -Os -static *.c -o out/roguelike `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lm

debug: lazy_compile
    lldb .out/roguelike launch

run: compile
    ./out/roguelike
```

i tried to fiddle around with some packages but it didn't work,
and i can't understand most of the tutorials on how to use lldb
so i don't really know what it is, specially the last line

Comment: In addition to the answer below, I don't see `-g` in your flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch `lldb` with

```
lldb out/roguelike launch
```

or

```
lldb ./out/roguelike launch
```

but not with

```
lldb .out/roguelike launch
```

Also, not an error but you are including `-lm` twice.

And yes, what HolyBlackCat says in comments: Provide debug info, just replace your first `-lm` (linking flags should be placed at the end of the toolchain) with `-g` and it should work.

Comment: thanks. as i said i don't know much about lldb

Comment: There's a tutorial for lldb here: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/tutorial.html.  Also, lldb has a `help` command for finding ways to do things, and also `apropos` for searching in the help.  If you are familiar with gdb, there's also a gdb->lldb cheat sheet: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html.